# StoryBoard Different screen sizes iOS

Tags: ios, screen-size, sketchapp

I'm trying to make an app. I prepared the ui with sketch app.And I export the ui , it is like this:
[image]

I add some text field and button to View

[image]

But when I use Auto Layout and constraints buttons and text fields are going to another place.I need the use them like in the picture.What should I do ? Do you have any suggestion ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Notice the red arrow at the top right of your second screen shot. That is telling you that **your constraints are faulty**. Until you fix them, you will not see your interface widgets in the desired locations.

In general, as long as you see a red or yellow arrow in that spot, you need to work on your layout some more. Do not attempt to run a project when Interface Builder shows you that red or yellow arrow; your results will be disappointing, to say the least.

Comment: Ok I solved it but in 3.5" devices its seems like this. http://prntscr.com/7g7efp

Comment: Once you have made the red/yellow arrow go away, your constraints are your constraints - you must set them up in relation to the superview so they work on different screen sizes. But that is another question! I believe I have answered correctly the question you did ask, i.e. why your views "are going to another place."